# What could cause the environment variables to not get loaded from ~/.bashrc at boot?

Tags: bash, debian, kde, environment-variables

On one of my Debian11/KDE machines which uses X11, the environment variables don't get loaded from ~/.bashrc at boot and `echo $PATH` only prints very few (but not none!) variables. After booting I have to run `. ~/.bashrc`.

What could be causing this? Is that intended? Does it have something to do with grub which recently got updated? This does not happen on a Debian11/KDE machine with Wayland.

When I run `. ~/.bashrc` more than once, it adds the paths multiple times so the string that is output at `echo $PATH` gets longer.

Comment: Your  bashrc gets read when you start a bash shell, every time, for that shell, not during boot. So chances are you're not using bash (could be, there's other shells as well) or your bash is actually reading it, but something in it later than your setting of PATH overwrites the path again. You can try to log to a temporary file right after setting PATH to check that it's actually happening. A simple `echo "[$$] just set PATH to $PATH" >> /tmp/ bashrclog` would probably do, inserted directly after your `export PATH=` line

Comment: I'm using the Konsole of KDE and haven't changed the shell to something that's not default. `echo $PATH` is the first command that I run when opening a konsole terminal which is the first thing I'm doing after boot. If that line goes into .bashrc, wouldn't it just echo once when starting the konsole if it loads from bashrc but still not have any info why it's overwritten?

Comment: Correct! But you would then know that your bashrc is actually executed correctly

Comment: It is, couldn't add it then or edit the comment: it just has a log entry when it's loaded but that doesn't show what's causing the overwrite. When I open a new konsole window, and run the echo command, the path is like in the basrhc file without having to run the source command first.

Comment: Cool! That's good debugging. So, is the path still correct when you log it at the very end of your bash rc?